# why the width of elements are different after page load and after that moment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The situation is that I want to change the size of an element right after the page load. The problem is that the element did not change because the result returned by the function `getSearchBarWidth` was negative number. Something strange here is that console prints incorrect values of the width of the two element `web_logo` and `menu`; their width should be small, but in the console, the width of both elements are equal the parent element, which is a navigation bar. But later, I print out again the width of two element in console, the result was correct. Can someone explain this?

update: it seems because I don't specify the width of the navigation bar. So is there any other except specify the width of the parent element to get the correct width of its children right after page loads?

```
 <script src="js/function.js" defer></script>
```

Content of file js

```
// calculate the width of window and relevant element
function getSearchBarWidth(){
    var wWidth = $(window).width();
    var offset = 20; // distance between the search bar and each of the two next elements
    var offset_1 = 15; // padding of each sides of the navi bar
    var searchBarWidth = wWidth - $("#navi_bar > .web_logo").width() - $("#navi_bar > .menu").width() - 2*offset - 2*offset_1;

    return searchBarWidth;
}

// change the size of search bar
if($("#navi_bar > .search_bar").length > 0){
    console.log("window: "+ $(window).width());
    console.log("logo: "+ $("#navi_bar > .web_logo").width());
    console.log("menu: "+ $("#navi_bar > .menu").width());
    $("#navi_bar > .search_bar").css("width", getWindowWidth());    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. Just call setTimeout and then the width of element would be correct.